# How To Put Data At Run Time In a Table i.e Table Also Create At The Run Time?

Tags: c#

i am trying to put data as a summery in my application from data table in a label but i want to put data in a table inspite of label such that table also create a t run time wile my code is putting data ina label at run time .. .

```
 for (int m = 0; m < dtGroupedByDate.Rows.Count; m++)
 {
      Label Date = new Label();
      Date.Text = dtGroupedByDate.Rows[m][0].ToString();
      Date.Style["margin-left"] = (m > 0) ? "20px" : "0px";
      this.Controls.Add(Date);
      Label PowerSum = new Label();
      PowerSum.Text = dtGroupedByDate.Rows[m][1].ToString();
      PowerSum.Style["margin-left"] = "20px";
      this.Controls.Add(PowerSum);
 }
```

Hopes for your suggestions... 
Regards,

Comment: not getting what you want ? please elaborate it more ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma an now in my code i am putting data to the label at run time from the data table i want to put data at run time from the data table to the table then obviously table would also create at run time

Comment: @Syed Raza, you're code basically looks like it should do what you are asking.  The part that seems to be missing is the query to the database (or where ever you are getting your data from).  Is this what you need help with?  This might be a good starting place for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose your data is in a datatable dt

then

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Table mytable = new Table();
        this.Controls.Add(mytable);
        mytable.DataBind(dt);
```

Comment: Hi Vikky, as you mentioned the code by doing this data from the table will bind to the data table?? i mean that i have date and power values in my data table and i want to show them in one line so that the result would like .. . 1 july  123   2 july  245... and so on..

Comment: see , this will simple bind the data to the table as in the datatable , if you want formatted table as per your demand you can use css for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.aspx) control

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.rows.aspx) you can find an example of looping through a list and adding rows dynamically.